# multipeer connectivity available * in osx? * in mixed ad-hoc/infra mode?

Tags: ios, macos, multipeer-connectivity

Here are two general questions about new iOS7 multipeer connectivity that google wasn't helpful with:

- does it run on osx (for osx - ios connectivity)? If not, is there any evidence that this might be supported in future?
- does it support discovery in wifi ad-hoc mode when one of the devices is connected to an access point in infrastructure mode? (Think walking by a Starbucks. I'm thinking it might be a possibility if iPhone has virtual network interfaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Multipeer Connectivity framework is only available for iOS at this time and there's no indication from Apple if Mac will support this framework in the future. A [quick search](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=multipeer) of the Mac documentation library is generally where I start with these types of questions. If it's not documented, it's not supported.

If you would like to see this framework supported on the Mac, you can always [file a request](http://bugreport.apple.com/) with Apple.

Comment: thanks - any idea re the other question part? Here's a similar one that implies a yes for OSX, but it was written before airdrop got to iOS: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28473/multiple-simultaneous-wifi-connections

Comment: It's not possible as iOS doesn't support virtual network interfaces. It does, however, support discovery between Bluetooth only and WiFi only devices if there is at least one device with both Bluetooth and WiFi enabled like [this](http://cl.ly/SDE7).

Answer (score 2):

Apple announced that the Multipeer Connectivity Framework will be supported on the Mac in the upcoming release of OS X Yosemite, read more [here](http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/05/apple-brings-multipeer-connectivity-to-mac-enables-cross-platform-nearby-networking-w-ios/)